# In MarioKart Wii, can the "View Replay" have different viewing angles each time?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

In MarioKart Wii, can the "View Replay" have different viewing angles each time, maybe either by the player pressing a button to change view, or by the console randomly show different views (for the replay of race results)?  It seems to be showing the same angle every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there are only two modes:

1. Automatic changing viewing angles throughout the replay
2. constantly show the angle as if the player is playing

and they can be altered using the `-` button.  This works for all replays, for yours or Ghost or World Rankings.